# How does "Follow Chess" stream live chess games?

Tags: live-streaming, chess

The app is available at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pereira.live - this is a very popular app, but I"m not sure how the app gets live scores. I've searched all over the internet but cannot find any API that streams this

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all it, it might not be a public API. Quite possible that Fallow Chess agreed with chess24.com for cooperative work and the API is protected. The things you can do:

You can sniff your Android network traffic and see where the requests are going. Still if it is not public API, you can't use it.

The other thing you/they can do (which regarding to some terms and laws might be illegal **!!**) with a web crawler to fetch/process the data from the site and send it to the app. Firebase is a great technology for such cases.

---

Comment: Common technique is just manually relay the games. It's not very hard work if you have a team in the office.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is very simple... If there is a way that they can fetch data from external sources, they'll do it. Otherwise, they'll do the moves manually. Follow Chess is managed by a small team of Indian developers. They can just sit and relay the moves during the games.

**PS**: Follow Chess is not very popular, in particular when you compare it with what chess24 can offer.